# Trying to ask user confirmation for discord.py bot command, but doing so neglects the "if and elif block" entirely

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have imported everything needed for the command.
So, the issue here is, in the condition for executing the command (checking if the user said yes/no or something weird which terminates the command)

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def nuke(self, ctx,*, channel = None, reason = None):
        
        if reason is None:
           reason = "No reason was specified!"
        if channel is None:
           channel = ctx.channel
        p = time.strftime(f'Today at %H:%M %p')
        embei = discord.Embed(color=0xa3a3ff, title = ":warning: ALERT ALERT ALERT :warning: ", description=f"{ctx.author.mention} Are you sure you want to delete {ctx.channel.mention}? y/n")
        await ctx.send(embed=embei)
        msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message:message.author == ctx.author and message.channel.id == ctx.channel.id)
        
        if msg.content.lower in ("y", "yes"):
         embedis = discord.Embed(color=0xa3a3ff, title=f"Channel ({ctx.channel.name}) has been nuked :boom:", description=f"Nuked by: {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator} \n **Reason:** {reason}")
         embedis.set_image(url = "https://66.media.tumblr.com/23dad7011515a9c21647fefb07e1c0e0/dd0cbd9bb94e2a45-1e/s640x960/a02fc34abff6953c59adafc190de6e5276969175.gif")
         embedis.set_footer(text=f"Rylie -  Thanks for using this bot! - {p} - {self.client.version}", icon_url = str(self.client.user.avatar_url))
         await ctx.channel.delete(reason=reason)
         channel = await ctx.channel.clone()
         await channel.send(embed=embedis)

        elif msg.content.lower in ("n", "no"):
            embegs = discord.Embed(color=0xa3a3ff, title = ":red_circle: NOTICE :red_circle:", description = f"{ctx.channel.mention} was not nuked!")
            embegs.set_footer(text=f"Rylie -  Thanks for using this bot! - {p} - {self.client.version}",  icon_url = str(self.client.user.avatar_url))
            await ctx.send(embed=embegs)
        else:
            embers = discord.Embed(color=0xa3a3ff, title = ":red_circle: NOTICE :red_circle:", description = "No proper response was given, action was terminated")
            embers.set_footer(text=f"Rylie -  Thanks for using this bot! - {p} - {self.client.version}",  icon_url = str(self.client.user.avatar_url))
            await ctx.send(embed=embers)
```

The part with the issue

```
        msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message:message.author == ctx.author and message.channel.id == ctx.channel.id)
        if msg.content.lower in ("y", "yes"):
         embedis = discord.Embed(color=0xa3a3ff, title=f"Channel ({ctx.channel.name}) has been nuked :boom:", description=f"Nuked by: {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator} \n **Reason:** {reason}")
         embedis.set_image(url = "https://66.media.tumblr.com/23dad7011515a9c21647fefb07e1c0e0/dd0cbd9bb94e2a45-1e/s640x960/a02fc34abff6953c59adafc190de6e5276969175.gif")
         embedis.set_footer(text=f"Rylie -  Thanks for using this bot! - {p} - {self.client.version}", icon_url = str(self.client.user.avatar_url))
         await ctx.channel.delete(reason=reason)
         channel = await ctx.channel.clone()
         await channel.send(embed=embedis)

        elif msg.content.lower in ("n", "no"):
            embegs = discord.Embed(color=0xa3a3ff, title = ":red_circle: NOTICE :red_circle:", description = f"{ctx.channel.mention} was not nuked!")
            embegs.set_footer(text=f"Rylie -  Thanks for using this bot! - {p} - {self.client.version}",  icon_url = str(self.client.user.avatar_url))
            await ctx.send(embed=embegs)
        else:
            embers = discord.Embed(color=0xa3a3ff, title = ":red_circle: NOTICE :red_circle:", description = "No proper response was given, action was terminated")
            embers.set_footer(text=f"Rylie -  Thanks for using this bot! - {p} - {self.client.version}",  icon_url = str(self.client.user.avatar_url))
            await ctx.send(embed=embers)
```

when I execute the command, it does ask me for the confirmation as expected, however, the reply here doesn't matter as it always executes the else statement. I thought the issue was with indentation and so I tried fixing that but that too didn't work. Does anyone know about the issue here I might be facing?

Extra: Before Adding user confirmation, the code was working absolutely fine! (It created a clone of the channel, sent the embed there saying it nuked the original channel, and deleted the original channel)

[image]

[image]

Comment: string.lower() is a method, you need to call it

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? Instantiate a string, use your same if/elif/else conditions but just print a string. Then run that as a simple script. I agree with @ŁukaszKwieciński , OP probably has an issue with the condition. The discord API and interaction isn't relevant to the problem

Comment: Also logging out or printing the given input BEFORE the if/elif/else would ensure the input is being captured.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I found the issue as everyone said, the script was wrong. I fixed the issue by declaring a list a and b, a = ["y", "yes"] and b = ["n", "no"], then I changed the `msg.content.lower` to `msg.content` 
`if msg.content in a:
elif msg content in b:
else:`

and now it works!
Thanks again for the help!

(Before doing so, I did try doing it in MCVE as Freiheit asked for, this is where I understood the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question of mine, `the string.lower()` is a method which I need to call, which was mentioned to me by Lukasz. I was using the `string.lower()` in the wrong way.

To Fix the problem I had, I declared two lists `a` and `b`

```
a=["y", "yes"]
b = ["n", "no"]
```

and changed

```
if msg.content.lower in ("y", "yes"):
elif msg.content.lower in ("n", "no"):
```

to

```
if msg.content in a:
elif msg.content in b:
```

and the issue was fixed.

Comment: you could change the message content to all lowercase, so the user can input `Y` and it will still detect it.